# Is it possible to set a custom thumbnail image for viewables using Autodesk Forge Model-Derivative API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have translated a few files using Forge APIs. I can view these files in the viewer. However, I am not happy with the thumbnails of these files. I want to set new custom thumbnails and want to know if I can replace the default one?

Comment: If you meant to replace the generated thumbnails via GET :urn/thumbnail
(https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-thumbnail-GET/) with your custom ones then that's unfortunately not yet possible - but I am unsure why you'd need to do such? You can easily use your own thumbnails in your own app?

Comment: Thanks Bryan,
Yes, that is a valid solution. Thanks.
Earlier we were not storing anything at our application's end so we wanted to change the associated data with the viewable.
Also, it would have been easier to share the same thumbnails across multiple applications if the original one itself was changed. But it's only a possibility for now.